# Auto Refresh in Trading View Charting Library in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, tradingview-api

I am encountering an issue with implementing auto-refresh for a TradingView chart in a React application. I have integrated the UDF adapter API for the data feed URL, and the chart is rendering correctly. However, I am facing challenges in implementing the auto-refresh functionality.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { widget } from "../../charting_library";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import datafeed from "./datafeed";

function getLanguageFromURL() {
  const regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]lang=([^&#]*)");
  const results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  return results === null
    ? null
    : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

function TVChartContainer(props) {
  console.log("props", props);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    symbols: props.symbols,
    pre_symbols: props.pre_symbols,
  });
  const [tvWidget, setTvWidget] = useState(null);

  const widgetOptionsFunc = (widgtProp) => {
    let symbols = widgtProp.symbols;
    if (widgtProp.pre_symbols && widgtProp.pre_symbols !== widgtProp.symbols) {
      symbols = widgtProp.symbols;
    }

    const widgetOptions = {
      debug: false,
      symbol: symbols,
      theme: props.theme === "dark" ? "Dark" : "Light",
      // BEWARE: no trailing slash is expected in feed URL
      datafeed: new window.Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed(
        widgtProp.datafeedUrl
      ),
      interval: widgtProp.interval,
      container_id: widgtProp.containerId,
      library_path: widgtProp.libraryPath,

      locale: getLanguageFromURL() || "en",

      disabled_features: [
        "header_compare",
        "header_saveload",
        "header_settings",
        "header_undo_redo",
        "header_screenshot",
        "header_fullscreen_button",
        "main_series_scale_menu",
        "countdown",
        "go_to_date",
        "timeframes_toolbar",
      ],
      enabled_features: ["hide_resolution_in_legend"],
      charts_storage_url: widgtProp.chartsStorageUrl,
      charts_storage_api_version: widgtProp.chartsStorageApiVersion,
      client_id: widgtProp.clientId,
      user_id: widgtProp.userId,
      fullscreen: widgtProp.fullscreen,
      autosize: widgtProp.autosize,
      studies_overrides: widgtProp.studiesOverrides,
      favorites: {
        intervals: ["1H", "2H", "4H", "6H", "12H", "1D", "3D", "2D", "1W"],
        chartTypes: ["ha"],
      },
      header_compare: false,
    };

    return new widget(widgetOptions);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const tvWidget = widgetOptionsFunc(props, state.symbols);
    // Assuming you have a way to persist tvWidget, e.g., using state or refs
    // For simplicity, let's assume it's a state variable
    setTvWidget(tvWidget);

    // Cleanup function to remove the widget on component unmount
    return () => {
      if (tvWidget !== null) {
        tvWidget.remove();
        setTvWidget(null);
      }
    };
  }, [props, state.symbols]);

  // Function to periodically update the chart
  const autoRefreshChart = () => {
    if (tvWidget !== null) {
      tvWidget.update();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(autoRefreshChart, 30000); // Auto-refresh every 30 seconds

    // Cleanup function to clear the interval on component unmount
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [tvWidget]);

  return <div id={props.containerId} className={"TVChartContainer"} />;
}

TVChartContainer.defaultProps = {
  interval: "1H",
  containerId: "tv_chart_container",
  datafeedUrl: "http://localhost:5000/api/chart",
  libraryPath: "/charting_library/",
  chartsStorageUrl: "https://saveload.tradingview.com",
  chartsStorageApiVersion: "1.1",
  header_widget_buttons_mode: "fullsize",
  clientId: "localhost",
  fullscreen: false,
  autosize: true,
  studiesOverrides: {},
  supportSymbolSearch: false,
  compare_symbols: false,
  disabled_features: [
    "save_chart_properties_to_local_storage",
    "volume_force_overlay",
  ],
  enabled_features: ["move_logo_to_main_pane", "study_templates"],
  disableSave: true,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    theme: state.AuthReducer.switch_theme,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TVChartContainer);
```

The auto-refresh function is intended to update the chart every 30 seconds. I have utilized setInterval within a useEffect hook to achieve this. However, it seems that the chart is not updating as expected.